# Label elements based on uniqueness

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a sorted array like so -

```
[[ 0    ]
 [ 0    ]
 [ 0    ]
 [ 3    ]
 [ 4    ]
 [ 15   ]
 [ 17   ]
 [ 87   ]
 [ 87   ]
 [ 87   ]
 [ 92   ]
 [ 180  ]
 [ 180  ]
 [ 215  ]
 [ 602  ]
 [ 1254 ]]
```

I want to label array elements based on their uniqueness. Thus, repeated values should take the same labels. The starting duplicated `0` elements would be labeled as `0` and rest should be consecutive numbers. Later on in the array, there are three `87` values and they should be labeled the same as `5` and then the two `180` values should be labeled as `7`'. The final output I am looking for would be -

```
[[    0       0  ]
 [    0       0  ]
 [    0       0  ]
 [    3       1  ]
 [    4       2  ]
 [   15       3  ]
 [    17      4  ]
 [    87      5  ]
 [    87      5  ]
 [    87      5  ]
 [    92      6  ]
 [   180      7  ]
 [   180      7  ]
 [   215      8  ]
 [   602      9  ]
 [  1254     10  ]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop through your array and when the current element is different from the previous then increment your counter and append the count to the current element like so

```
count = 0
prev = l[0][0]
for i in l:
    if i[0] != prev:
        prev = i[0]
        count+=1
    i.append(count)

print np.array(l)


[[   0    0]
 [   0    0]
 [   0    0]
 [   3    1]
 [   4    2]
 [  15    3]
 [  17    4]
 [  87    5]
 [  87    5]
 [  87    5]
 [  92    6]
 [ 180    7]
 [ 180    7]
 [ 215    8]
 [ 602    9]
 [1254   10]]
```

Comment: Since the OP is specifically interested in an array solution, you should do `np.array(i)` at the end.

Comment: SirParselot, thank you so much your interesting and response. its very useful thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to find IDs based on uniqueness among the elements which can be obtained by the optional argument `return_inverse` used in [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), like so -

```
_,idx = np.unique(A,return_inverse=True)
```

Sample run :

1) Input array -

```
In [86]: A
Out[86]: 
array([[   0],
       [   0],
       [   0],
       [   3],
       [   4],
       [  15],
       [  17],
       [  87],
       [  87],
       [  87],
       [  92],
       [ 180],
       [ 180],
       [ 215],
       [ 602],
       [1254]])
```

2) Get unique IDs for all elements and display them alongside input elements -

```
In [87]: _,idx = np.unique(A,return_inverse=True)

In [88]: np.column_stack((A,idx))
Out[88]: 
array([[   0,    0],
       [   0,    0],
       [   0,    0],
       [   3,    1],
       [   4,    2],
       [  15,    3],
       [  17,    4],
       [  87,    5],
       [  87,    5],
       [  87,    5],
       [  92,    6],
       [ 180,    7],
       [ 180,    7],
       [ 215,    8],
       [ 602,    9],
       [1254,   10]])
```

Comment: Divakar, thanks so much for your help it is very useful for me. Thanks again and again....